# Reading my csv file in python generates encoded data

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding

I have a problem reading a csv file on python, although I can have access to my data via Excel.

Bellow is the script I have tried to read the file:

```py
import csv

with open('theFile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    reader = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

N.B: I added `errors:'ignore'`to  avoid the following error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 16: invalid continuation byte`

It's "working", it doesn't return errors, but the data displayed is encoded in some syntax I don't know (it's a mixture of ascii, chineese, arabic ...), yet organized in brackets (I assume it's the rows and lines). Here is a sample of the resulting data I have:

```
...

 ['#']
[';eTbv܅']
['=\x17Ҥ\x14\x1d4Xrߋ{b@.8d˽\x01\x1eד&\x05;mt`O']
['\x06^CLqgL\x14', '\te0Z\x7f>:|w.{\x062>;\x11d\\oT5\x07̫\x14d\\6', 'a4Ku榏\x01U|\x01.%FH']
['\x1c%\x13\x1eZ֛Eu>\x1b{tz\x1d\\-7~Yll?\x11Gp\x0f߈v"UhT\x04IF\x1dFK[W&d\x0bK|\x01[>v`KY8rE', "DF4qKcb2+Gta/DO\x1e!7\x11×\x13cJQ*I9E*o\x1f!\x19W֭}d3\x1afʤ'¢d\x19\\vP;$\x0b"]
['_(]\x17\x1atTPL翬}J;R\x12Hl4~amB\x0b1kf]`\x05H8d2s{}|K(DJ\x02\x1f˪*c\x18\x7fa8%e7=QLJ2udj^&. <\t\x18cI4魚\x08I62QM\x11\x0fܡ\x1c*QLv\x11uY"\x7f1·E"ڟ%̉.r\x12dԣz\x13', '+ZDVsx|L\\6QM<I']

...

['iβg']
['\x06c<PUc0\x1a=e\x7fx&%握\x18\x1cW-i\x19LǗ^zh\x1ag']
["\x10R\x7f&\x14*ʞ\x06SQ1\x0e)Z\\Q\x0c8\\%TP\x1bnh[1iҪEC!f-E\x1d\x12v8h!ZX]pc$\x19O9k\x1974'FA;E_mag0p;U[\x0fŔg\x18'wsסn_\x06\x7f8$mA", 'y%\x02#\x10ӾM\x11"FP\x1b\x1ett\x08X^vu\x01b9Wb)y]u\x0b\x03PK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!ȣ4v\x01\x04\x05\x13[Content_Types].xmlPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!U0#L\x02\x0b\x03_rels/.relsPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!>\x02\x1ap\x06xl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!\x17XG\x01\x14\x02\x0f\x08xl/workbook.xmlPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!\x14\x04^\x04\x0c\x14\x18']
['xl/sharedStrings.xmlPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!;m2KB\x01#\x0exl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.relsPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!\x12_\x06T\x1b\x13\x0fxl/theme/theme1.xmlPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!j9Ա\x02\x04\x0c']
["a\x16xl/styles.xmlPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!\x06*z\x04\x06\x17\x18J\x19xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!H\x0e\x1d'\x04xl/printerSettings/printerSettings1.binPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!}\x10A\x01[\x02\x11\x04docProps/core.xmlPK\x01\x02-\x14\x06\x08!c", '(\x010\x03\x10\x19\x04docProps/app.xmlPK\x05\x06\x0c\x0c&\x03\x04']
```

Here is a screen shot of the csv file (that I had fun modifying for this post ^^):

[image: Some of the csv data]

All I want is to have access to the data without ruining it. I'm then open to other methods and I can easily modify the type of the file (even if I have already tried, in vain, with the dbf type).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i recommend using the `read_csv` function from pandas

Comment: are you sure the data is utf-8? it may be another standard of csv

Comment: I have the following error: ```ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 3```
this is what I wrote: ```df = pd.read_csv("theFile.csv")```

Comment: @JosephHolland I'm not sure actually, but it's definitly not utf-16 since it doesn't start with BOM  ;)

Comment: csv files are made of text.

Comment: Your file is not utf8-encoded. You need to use the right encoding.

Comment: @snakecharmerb , it's modified from an xlsx file but has a csv extention. So I guess it's a csv? However, I'm not sure of the type of encoding

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I think you're right, I've tried some command (to change the encoding type to rot13) & I've got this error: ```TypeError: descriptor 'translate' requires a 'str' object but received a 'bytes'``` 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Goyo ,
In my last  trial, I didn't use the encoding type and it worked well for me.
```import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('theFile.csv', newline=''), delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```
Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using `codecs`?

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('theFile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for row in f:
        print(row)
```

Humm. I have an ugly suggestion. It seems like the file you've shared in this link opens well with Google Sheets. So just open it and `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+C`, create a new `theFile.csv` manually, open it and do `Ctrl+V`. Use the above code to open this new file. It opens as you want, just verified.

Comment: Thank you for thee suggestion,
It returns an encoded stuff also, but with other symbols ^^'

Comment: It would be nice if you can share a smaple csv file via a link

Comment: All right, 
link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b73118hQ2Ex3hgEbJlEf4DTo74PynAKG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see my ugly suggestion above :D.

Comment: Oh niice!
it still doesn't work for me (I guess it's an internal problem)
Thank you for your time =)

Comment: Did you try copying stuff from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b73118hQ2Ex3hgEbJlEf4DTo74PynAKG/edit#gid=1114647168

Comment: Yes, and it only gave me an xlxs file ^^'